# GeoJSON data visible in browser but not showing on map

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, geojson

I am using OpenLayers, GeoServer and Shapefiles.

I have published the shapefile to GeoServer and under layer preview I can see JSON data in browser when I select GeoJSON option from the dropdown for that file.

Problem is I cannot get the data to display on the map in OpenLayers.

[This is the link I followed](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html)

And here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent){
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/toiletlisttrial/ows?service=WFS'
        +'&version=1.0.0'
        +'&request=GetFeature'
        +'&typeName=toiletlisttrial:toilet_list_trial'
        +'&maxFeatures=50'
        +'&outputFormat=application/json'
        +'&srsname=EPSG:4326';
        },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 2
          })
        })
      });

      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          raster,
          vector
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also read somewhere that I need to load features from URL dynamically using AJAX calls. If so, how would I do that? I didn't find anything beginner friendly on the subject.

Comment: You need to reproject your data from 4326 to 3857

Comment: I tried adding dataProjection='EPSG:4326' and featureProjection: 'EPSG:3867' to vectorSource but it didn't work.
I also tried adding just projection: 'EPSG:3857' but that didn't work either. How can I reproject data from 4326 to 3857?